# Do Kudos have any purpose?

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

When visiting the camping of another player, you can give him some Kudos. You can also receive Kudos from other players for your own camping. But is there any purpose to this? Do you win anything after getting a certain amount of Kudos, or are you allowed to echange them for something else in the game? I tried to look around in the game and on different guides, but was not able to find any information about this anywhere, leading me to think Kudos don't have any other purpose than showing to a player that you like his camping (or just do your daily missions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kudos only does two things at this time. (From what I have found online and seen for myself).

**1)** Tells another player you like their camp (or liked what their market box had and you've purchased it etc).

**2)** Fulfills goals that earn you friendship powder used in crafting. This is obtained no other way. *

*It does seem like you get a kudos based daily goal each day to allow you to earn the powder at least a little per day.

Comment: You can now get powder other ways: watering people’s gardens and sharing butterflies/bats during the safari.

Comment: Also the kudos goal has been removed (although powder still shows up occasionally as a reward)

Answer (score -1):

I’ve received 10 coins every time someone gives me kiddos  maybe it does that too? But I’m not sure

Comment: The 10 coins is from helping others at the quarry, not from kudos

Answer (score -2):

It seems like whenever I give kudos, I get 100 coins. I'm not sure,  though. Trying to pick up more about the game, even though I've been playing awhile...

Comment: The 100 coins is from helping your friends enter Shovelstrike Quarry. You get 100 coins if they used the Quarry that day, or 10 if they didn't.